# Powershell - Get Last Logon

Tags: powershell

I have a quick script I am trying to reuse from getting computers lastlogon.  Due to time constraints I am posting it here for assistance.  I am trying to use the display name and even tried using the sam, but no luck.

```
$results = @()
$CompanyUsers = import-csv c:\bin\users.csv

foreach ($i in $CompanyUsers)
    {
    $results += Get-Aduser -Filter $i.sam -Properties * | select Name, Lastlogondate 
    #$results += Get-Aduser -Filter {displayname -eq $i.displayname} -Properties * | select Name, Lastlogondate 
    }

$results | export-csv c:\bin\Userslogon.csv
```

I get syntax errors. I can manually put in the values so I am thinking it has to do with data types extracted from the array.  Suggestions would be appreciated!

SAM ERROR:
Get-Aduser : Error parsing query: 'xxx001' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '1'.
At C:\bin\Get-UserLastLogon.ps1:19 char:14
+     $results += Get-Aduser -Filter $i.sam -Properties * | select Name, Lastlogondat ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error parsing query: 'kal001' Error Message: 'syntax error' at posi 
   tion: '1'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

DISPLAYNAME ERROR:
Get-Aduser : Property: 'displayname' not found in object of type: 
'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.
At C:\bin\Get-UserLastLogon.ps1:20 char:17
+     $results += Get-Aduser -Filter {displayname -eq $i.displayname} -Properties  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Property: 'displayname' not found in object of type: 'System.Manage 
   ment.Automation.PSCustomObject'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Thanks for the suggestions.  I found a way to get this to work:

```
# Create array of users
$results = @()
$Users = Get-Content C:\bin\fullnames.txt

# Get last logon date
foreach($i in $Users)
    {
    $results += Get-ADUser -ldapfilter "(displayname=$i)" -Property * | Select-Object -Property name, samaccountname, lastlogondate
    } 

# Export results to csv file
$results | export-csv c:\bin\logonusers.csv
```

Comment: It will be quicker if you post the text of the error you're getting so we don't have to guess at what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
Get-Aduser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$i.sam'" -Properties * 

Get-Aduser -Filter "displayname -eq '$i.displayname'" -Properties *
```

The samaccountname will be faster, since that's an indexed property.

Comment: The errors are gone, but I am not getting any data exported to my csv file.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create array of users
$results = @()
$Users = Get-Content C:\bin\fullnames.txt

# Get last logon date
foreach($i in $Users)
    {
    $results += Get-ADUser -ldapfilter "(displayname=$i)" -Property * | Select-Object -Property name, samaccountname, lastlogondate
    } 

# Export results to csv file
$results | export-csv c:\bin\logonusers.csv
```